How can I combine two types in Python similar to using "&" in TypeScript?
Say, I have two types A and B. How can I concatenate these types into a type that has all members of A and B?
In TypeScript I would use the & operator: A & B:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/use-intersection-types-to-combine-types-in-typescript
How can I achieve the same in Python?

Are you asking about type hinting or combining actual classes? Some (pseudo)code example would be useful.

You can use | for the variable, because it means that you are defining a union type. or you can use typing.Union.

no, this the OP is asking for an intersection type, not a union type

then they can use Intersection from typing module rather than union

that doesn't exist

@juanpa.arrivillaga yes it does exist https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#special-forms

@oriraisfeld nowhere in your link is an intersection type described. Those are union types.

you just add | to the variable, so:
x: A | B = A()

no, the OP is asking for an intersection type, not a union type

i know, but that's not what he's describing here in the URL he sent for the example code ( https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/use-intersection-types-to-combine-types-in-typescript )  what he is doing is can be achieved by the union type in python

@oriraisfeld No, it can't. Using the union type, will allow the user to pass either of the individual type, and a type having all fields will not be accepted

i don't think that will be the case because it's python, so the types don't mean anything (besides helping IDEs in understanding code and some specific cases). maybe it's just my IDE, but it seemed to be working perfectly fine when converting all of the code in the blog from TS to PY

@oriraisfeld it is taken as a given that questions about type hinting are about getting the type annotations to be valid under PEP 484 (and subsequent expansions) and for commonly used tools like mypy and pyright. What IDE are you using that is understanding a union type to work as an intersection type? I would ditch that IDE
